# OCR on striked-out text

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr

I have the following image with me:

[image]

I want to identify the text, which is the amount mentioned at the bottom of the table. However, the bottom edge of the table goes through the text in this case.

How do I go about trying to extract this text?

PS: For now, I am just using tesseract. However, tesseract was unable to identify this text.

Comment: Have you tried some preprocessing (e.g. sharping)? Maybe it will help. Also consider extracting region where you expect your text to appear.

Comment: maybe apply morphological opening to remove the long horizontal/vertical lines, similar to this: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html

Comment: More generally, you have two possible approaches: either apply bespoke cropping and filters (possibly using `opencv`) or try shoot-in-the-dark deep learning, possibly one-shop, like the work in [these papers](http://www.citeulike.org/user/mapto/tag/text_detection). Most of the papers come with github repositories for their code.